# Visual Studio Code set up for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS core under Windows 7. When I try to run a really simple python script, it gives the attached error.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI _program_ is misspelled in the error as _pogram_. Perhaps this is relevant?

Comment: Next time please just post the text of the error message. It's easier and quicker to read. Also, pay very very close attention to error messages and think very very carefully about what they say. This one was very obvious if you'd been paying attention to it and not running off in a confused panic.